# Displaying short description of post under post name using Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I'm using jekyll with GitHub pages for my blog. How can I display a short sentence right below my post title in the index/ home page? As an example, I am trying to write text between the red brackets:

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gi5g.png)

I've seen other posts on this site that ask a similar question, but they are very old and it seems that jekyll has changed since then. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If these are posts you should be able to use `{{ post.excerpt }}`. You can see more in the docs: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/

If it's a page (and not a post) you'll need to use `{{ page.content | truncatewords: 30 }}`. See more in the docs: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/truncatewords/

A note about `page.content`: if that page is HTML code you'll need to use the `strip_html` filter. If that page has liquid, there is no filter to strip that and you will need to add the excerpt to the front matter. Something like this:

```
---
title: This is a post title
description: This is a post description.
excerpt: This is the post excerpt.
---

{{ page.excerpt }}
```